# How to change a value inside a dictionary in an array that's inside a dictionary?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a plist dictionary with several arrays where each have different number of items. These items are dictionaries too. So basically it looks like this:

- Root dictionary

  - names array
  - places array
    - Item 0 dictionary
    - Item 1 dictionary
      - placeName string: "House"
      - description string: "My House"
      - height number: 10
    - Item 2 dictionary
    - ...
  - colors array
  - ...

I want to find the best way to change a value inside one of these arrays (placeName, description, height).

The plist is part of the resources, so I call it in like this:

```
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initFromName:@"mydefaults.plist"];
```

I've seen the setValue:forKey methods, but it looks like I'm heading into a mess.
I don't think I should have to be setting the whole complete array if it's just one value.

So, which is the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something along the lines of

```
[[[plistDictionary objectForKey:@"places"] objectAtIndex:1] setValue:@"Another house" forKey:@"placeName"]
```

if the "internal" arrays and dictionaries are indeed mutable.

Comment: Yes; that you edit the dictionary in memory does not mean it gets saved to disk. You need a `[plistDictionary writeToFile:... atomically:...]` somwehere.